# Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080: unexpected error Permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am on windows 10 ent

Running command: docker container run -d -p 8080:80 --name mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql

But I am getting this error:

docker:  Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mysql(969f8eac66c92e42a4f19f6f28eec72c6802fea1eabed48dfb382c6a35cbb2ce)Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080: unexpected error Permission denied.

Need help.

Comment: try on another port

Comment: Something may be already running on port 8080

Comment: Is there any way by which I don't have to change the port. I mean how I can make port 8080 available?

Comment: Usage netstat -a -n -o

Answer (score 1):

This error is often caused because the port you specified is already in use. Sometimes it is because the current user does not have administrative rights.

If you do not specifically require port 80, try port 8000 or 8080.

docker container run -d -p 8080:8000 --name mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql

If that doesn't fix it, try executing the command in sudo as some ports are system protected and require a user with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

In all such cases where you are not sure which port is free on the host machine, 
you can try using -P option while running your images and then use docker port  to see it's bind with which port.

```
#>docker container run -d -P --name mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql

#>docker port mysql
3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768
docker@default:~$
```

After this you know which port is free then you can select that one and use your usual command.

```
#>docker container run -d -p 32768:80 --name mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql
```

However I think, instead of 80 - you must expose 3306 port - since the default mysql doesn't provide a web-interface.

Adminer (formerly phpMinAdmin) is a different application that does provide mysql server embedded with it.